# Proof of Convergence of K-means

Tags: linear-algebra

$T(e_1) = e_1+5e_2$ $T(e_2) = 2e_1+4e_2$

$T(e_2-e_1) = e_1 - e2$.

What is the rank and nullity of T? Isn't this the rank and nullity of $e_1-e_2$?

Is this asking what the rank and nullity of  $[1 ,-1]'$ is? Isn't the nullity just 0. And isn't the rank $1$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write down the matrix of $T$ in $e_1, e_2$ basis, you will get
$$
T=\begin{bmatrix}
1&2\\
5&4
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Matrix $T$ is non-degenerate $\det T = -6$, so matrix $T$ is of full rank, hence ${\rm rank} \; T = 2$.
According to rank–nullity theorem, nullity is zero.

Comment: Why is it not [1 5; 2 4]?

Comment: $T e_1 = [1\ 2;5\ 4] \cdot [1;0] = [1; 5]=e_1+5e_2$